# JPA not receiving updated data

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I use a managedBean that goes into the db and defines the bean properties with db data. However when I update the db the data I receive in my bean is not updated.

The query in db is like this:

```
    private static final String JPQL_FIND_BY_ID = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.idcategory=:id";
@Override
public Category findCatById(int id) {
    Query query = em.createQuery(JPQL_FIND_BY_ID, Category.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    Category cat = null;
    try {
        cat = (Category) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cat;
}
```

The managed bean I use to get the category asks the ejb to make a lookup in the db:

```
@ManagedBean
public class CategoryBean {
    private String idCategoryStr;
    private Category category;
    private int id;

    @EJB
    private CategoryLookUp categoryService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.category = categoryService.findCatById(id); //id defined in constructor
        System.out.println(this.category.getName());//this will give the same
                                             //name before and after db update
    }

    public CategoryBean() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> paramsMap = fc.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap();
        this.idCategoryStr = paramsMap.get("id");
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(idCategoryStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
//get&set
}
```

If I change the Title of the category in my db, it's gonna be unchanged in my bean even though @PostConstruct is called and the id is correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/forumcsDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>main.java.entities.Category</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Country</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Forum</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Message</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Post</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Thethread</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Usercfg</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Usercredential</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Userinfo</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.User</class>
    <class>main.java.entities.Friend</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've committed the changes you made at DB?

Comment: Do you have any cache configured?

Comment: @user3707125 when I refresh my server (this is a web app) the changes appear so yes they are committed.

Comment: @talex I'm not sure what you mean. If you see the init method, the data I get back from the db lookup is wrong. I didn't configure anything really. It's an eclipse project and I used jpa tool to get entities from the db tables.

Comment: You should check how JPA configured. There is a sing called Second Level Cache. It stores entities by id. When you request entity it check is entity already loaded and return result from memory if present.

Comment: @talex Ok. I found a nice link: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching . Thanks for the help Ima see if this works in an hour

Comment: @talex Ok it works. I added this to the persistence.xml :  <properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
 </properties>. Tell me if you want the karma for the answer else, I'll post this as answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason that you get old value is that your entity is stored in second level cache. And when you request it second time no database call is executed, but value from memory is returned.

You can disable cache by adding `<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>` to `property` section of your `persistence.xml`